# Scala Closures - how these closures work as parameters to high order functions

Tags: scala

I had the following code snippet and somehow i got it working . However, I didnt understand how these lines work

```
val x = List.range(1, 10)

val evens1 = x.filter((i: Int) => i % 2 == 0) // I understand this , closure is passed as  a function variable to filter function
val isEven = (i: Int) => i % 2 == 0
val evens = x.filter(i =>isEven(i)) // this is working, but i didnt understand this
val evens1 = x.filter(isEven(i))//why this is not working, how we can make this work
val evens2 = x.filter(isEven)//this works
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So for all cases remember that `filter` is a **method** on `List` which accepts a **function** as an argument.

```scala
val evens = x.filter((i: Int) => i % 2 == 0)
```

This is creating a **function** using the lambda syntax.
PS: This can be simplified as:

```scala
val evens = x.filter(i => i % 2 == 0)
// No need to provide the type of i, it is inferred by the context.
```

You may even simplify it even more like this:

```scala
val evens = x.filter(_ % 2 == 0)
// No need to name the parameter if it is only used once.
```

But I personally don't recommend abusing the `_` syntax, since it can be confusing.

---

```scala
val isEven = (i: Int) => i % 2 == 0
```

This creates a **function** using the lambda syntax and stores it in the `isEven` variable.

```scala
val evens = x.filter(i => isEven(i))
```

This is exactly the same as the first one; a lambda. Which is this case is redundant since the body of the lambda is just a function call.
That is why you can also do this:

```scala
val evens = x.filter(isEven)
```

---

Finally, this:

```scala
val evens1 = x.filter(isEven(i))
```

Won't work, since this is a compile error because there is no variable `i` defined anywhere; and even if there would be one then this would fail since `filter` expects an `Int => Boolean` and `isEven(i)` would return a plain `Boolean`

> how we can make this work

Is not possible to make this to work since what you want is not valid syntax.

*...*

Well, you may do this:

```scala
val evens = x.filter(isEven(_))
// Which would be equivalent to:
val evens = x.filter(i => isEven(i))
```

Or maybe you may do something like this:

```scala
def createPredicateEqualsTo(to: Int): Int => Boolean =
  i => i == to

val allTwos = x.filter(createPredicateEqualsTo(2))
```

But, this is way different to what you had since now I have a **method** that returns a **function** and I am calling it with a constant to create a predicate which will be passed down to `filter`

Comment: incredible answer. just one question - how this syntax "isEven(i)" is different from isEven(_). Both look "similar".  I know "_" is place holder syntax and will be replaced with "each element". But, how they work ? both seems to be function "calls"

Comment: @Nag the difference is that `i` is a valid identifier, whereas `_` is not; thus the compiler can have special rules when it sees `_` since that can't be a variable.